# How to label each graph with different x-axis name and y-axis name

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
fig_1 = plt.figure(1, figsize=(6.4, 4.8))

chart_1 = fig_1.add_subplot(121)
chart_2 = fig_1.add_subplot(122)

chart_1.plot(year, apl_price)
chart_2.plot(year, ms_price)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `chart_1.set_xlabel(...)`, `chart_1.set_ylabel(...)`... Also perhaps easier to do `fig_1, (chart_1, chart_2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(6.4, 4.8))`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using matplolib, you can use `matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel` and `matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel` :
[matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html)
[matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel.html)